# Identity theorem - entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Let $f$ an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that
>   $f(e^{it})=e^{it}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Compute $f(z)$ for all
>   $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Is anyone could give me a hint how to solve the problem?

Comment: I would have used the identity theorem with $f(z) -z$ on $D(0,2)$. Also you should have $r=1$ above.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you mean $f(z)= e^{it}$ on $D(0,2)$?

Comment: No. What you would have is that $f$ and $z$ agree on the unit circle. By the identity theorem, any two holomorphic functions which agree on a set with an accumulation point must be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easier: two analytic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ agreeing on a set with a limit point must be equal.  This function agrees with $z\mapsto z$ on the unit circle.